# how to write hive queries for following problems

Tags: hiveql

i have a table with 10 columns
ColumnNo    Name    Example DataType

Column1 athlete_name    Michael Phelps  STRING

Column2 age 23  INT
Column3 country United States   STRING

Column4 year    2008    INT

Column5 closing_date    8/24/2008   STRING

Column6 sport   Swimming    STRING

Column7 gold_medals 8   INT

Column8 silver_medals   0   INT

Column9 bronze_medals   0   INT

Column10    total_medals    8   INT

i have few queries to write

Find out the total number of medals won by each country in swimming
 Find out the total number of medals won by India in each year
 Find out the total number of medals won by each country and also display the name of the
country
 Find out the total number of gold medals won by each country
 Find out the country got medals for Shooting for each year

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i've tried to solve the first  one  like -->select country,count from (select country,sport, count(*) from usecase5 group by country,sport) ab where ab.sport= swimming;